# QBO3's Batch Apply does not apply to all matching records

Tags: sql-server, queue

In our QBO3 system, we have intermittant problems generating documents and saving them to our FTP site. When this occurs, the Workflow > Dashboard By Errors report will show us the errored steps.

Once our FTP server is no longer under load, I use `ImportFile/BatchApply` to re-execute the relevent workflow steps. Specifically, my query is:

```
DecisionStep/Search?DecisionStepTemplateID=X&ErrorDate!=&SqlFilter=Active&DisplaySize=0&Batch=1000
```

with an action of:

```
DecisionStep/Start?ID={DecisionStepID}
```

Observations:

- when I click Query, I see the appropriate results
- when I click Preview, I see the appropriate results
- when I click Batch, an Import File is created, all Import File Queue records are processed successfully
- the Workflow > Dashboard By Errors shows some errors remaining

Why are there errors remaining after using Batch Apply?

Answer (score 1):

In your query, you specify BatchSize=1000; this limits the results of the query to the top 1000 rows. **Set BatchSize to a value that is larger than your expected result set.** In this example, you should be able to determine your expected result set from Workflow > Dashboard By Errors.

---

**TLDR; Use BatchSize=25 for Query and Preview, then change it to 10000 for Batch.**

The UI for ImportFile/BatchApply offers 4 buttons:

- Query: executes your query so you can see the results in the browser,
- Preview: executes your query, and displays the matching Actions, so you can see the results in the browser,
- Apply: queues execution of the query + action for later execution as one long transaction, and
- Batch: queues execution of the query + action for later execution as an Import File.

The first two of these buttons hold the possibility of being **long-running transactions**, and timing out at the load balancer. The Apply and Batch buttons queue an operation, so it won't ever be a long-running transaction subject to a timeout.

When using the **Query and Preview** buttons, consider making your DisplaySize and **BatchSize reasonably small** (like 25 or 50), so you're less likely to be subjected to timeouts. When you're ready to **Apply or Batch**, you can change your DisplaySize / **BatchSize to a large value** (like 10000) so all matching records have the Action applied to them.